# Confused: my method will not accept the argument included in its definition

Tags: c#, wcf, class, methods, attributes

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase this, but here goes:

I have a custom class called ***EmailAttachment*** which has 3 properties/attributes defined. An object of this class is passed to a method (in another class, of course) called ***UploadAttachment***

```
void UploadAttachment(EmailAttachment attachment);
```

However, when I implement this using, for example,

```
client.UploadAttachment(emailAttachmentInstance)
```

Visual Studio tells me that ***UploadAttachment*** does not accept 1 argument instead it accepts 3 (ie the variables from the class definition).
This has me quite confused so any help is appreciated

---

To clarify a bit...

`client` is actually an instance of a WCF service. The service interface includes

```
[OperationContract]
void UploadAttachment(EmailAttachment attachment); //which is public.
```

Following is the class in question...

```
[MessageContract]
public class EmailAttachment
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public int EmailID;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream AttachmentFile;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code - just the declarations should be enough. We'll need to know what `client` is though...

Comment: Is that just an intellisense error? try building it.

Comment: I tried rebuilding it and updating the service reference several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my answer (partially conjecture/hypothesis of a friend)...
I guess it has to do with the nature of the WCF service. In order to prevent complications client-side  (i.e. being dependent on class(es) defined by the service), the client can pass the attributes/properties (the 3 mentioned previously) of the [service] class as the arguments of the method (in this case `UploadAttachment()`). Therefore, it only needs to know the data types of those attributes/properties, and does not have to instantiate an object of its class. The same can be done for custom return types.
For example, if `SomeClass` is defined as such...

```
[MessageContract]
public class SomeClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public bool value;

    public SomeClass(bool value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

...and the service has a method that returns a value of `SomeClass` like so...

```
SomeClass SomeMethod();
```

...the client can call `SomeMethod()` like so...

```
bool someReturnValue = client.SomeMethod();
```

instead of having to instantiate `SomeClass`.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without more information (can you post some code?) but if I may be permitted to guess I would say that the class which defines "client" has two methods called UploadAttachment, and the one you are trying to call is not public.  e.g.

```
public class Client {
  void UploadAttachment(EmailAttachment e) {}  //note: needs to be public
  public void UploadAttachment(int a, int b, int c) {}
}
```

Comment: If this turns out to be the right answer it's a masterful example of psychic debugging...